# glibc memcpy arm64 neon optimization

Tags: memory, arm, glibc, arm64

I am investigating glibc memcpy implementation for arm64(sysdeps/aarch64/memcpy.S). As far as I understand, it doesn't support NEON. There are NEON-optimized version for armv7, but arm64 is just based on common registers (this is also caught in GDB). Am I right, that glibc doesn't support NEON for memcpy? Why? (maybe because NEON couldn't bring performance boost for arm64?)

Comment: How do you know that 'neon' is an 'optimization'?  The arm64 registers are bigger and you have different ISA and CPU structure.  Probably this depends on the target specific as per [What is the faster way to copy memory on a Cortex-A8?](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.faqs/ka13544.html).  Ie, SDRAM characteristics and BUS interface will play a large role.

Comment: I am not claiming that NEON implementation is always faster with memory copy. I just interested why there are no NEON-version support for ARM64 in glibc, which exist, e.g. for armv7. I have allready read link, you mentioned, and finally NEON with pld is the best, but it's for 32 bit arm. I am interesting in knowledge for ARM64.

Comment: AArch64 has 64-bit registers and can load and store pairs of them for transactions that are the same size as a NEON register.  That might be sufficient to saturate the memory interface, in which case there's no point involving NEON.  NEON might be able to lower the instruction count for a certain sized transaction, but those instructions will just take longer and give no speed gain.